# Can i merge the result of two queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to retrieve some statistics from my database, to be concrete i'm look to show how many todo's is completed vs the total of a checklist.

The structure is as follows

A category has many Cards, has many checklists, has many assessments.

I can get the amount of assessments or completed assessments with the following query.

```
SELECT count(a.id) AS completed_count, a.checklist_id, ca.category_id
FROM assessments a
JOIN checklists ch ON ch.id = a.checklist_id
JOIN cards ca ON ca.id = ch.card_id
WHERE a.complete
GROUP BY a.checklist_id, ca.category_id;
```

This will give me something like this.

```
 completed_count | checklist_id | category_id 
-----------------+--------------+-------------
               2 |            3 |           2
               1 |            2 |           2
               2 |            5 |           3
```

I could then do a query, to get the total amount, by removing the `WHERE a.complete`, and write some code that matches the two results.

But what i really want, is a result like this.

```
 completed_amount | total_amount | checklist_id | category_id 
------------------+--------------+--------------+-------------
                2 |            2 |            3 |           2
                1 |            1 |            2 |           2
                2 |            2 |            5 |           3
```

I just can't wrap my head around, how i can achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think conditional aggregation does what you want:

```
SELECT sum( (a.complete)::int ) AS completed_count,
       count(*) as total_count
       a.checklist_id, ca.category_id
FROM assessments a JOIN
     checklists ch
     ON ch.id = a.checklist_id JOIN
     cards ca
     ON ca.id = ch.card_id
GROUP BY a.checklist_id, ca.category_id;
```